# Question about Macbook Hard-driver replacement

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, install

My OSX 10.8.2 crashed recently, I think I got a very good chance to replace my Hard drive as I need more storage. My question is: Can I seamlessly transfer my data (Include my iTunes music library and music playing history, iOS device synchronization record) to the new hard drive after replacing the hard drive WITHOUT using Time Machine? Because I got have no additional external hard drive for backup.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

For only a few dollars you can buy a Sata/usb external hard drive enclosure. Remove your old hard drive and put it into the enclosure. Boot your computer up using the external drive by holding down option when starting up and selecting your drive. Then download Carbon Copy Cloner (free). Using that you can clone over all your data to the new drive which you install in your computer. If you cannot boot, like that. Re-install 10.8 to the new drive in the data enclosure, then copy over all your data using Carbon Copy Cloner. If you want to backup your sync data and iTunes library, your iDevice backups are stored in your local library folder. "~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/" The iTunes library is stored in ~/Music/iTunes